# listbox shrinking while clicking command button

Tags: vba, excel, listbox

i have a problem where every time i click on the command button, my listbox on userform will shrink. my command button are suppose to filter data according to respective year inserted. the listbox returns all data filter but it keep on shrinking everytime i click command button.

this is my code on command button;

```
   Private Sub CommandButton5_Click()

Dim a, o() As Variant, n As Long
Dim i As Long, c As Long

Me.ListBox1.RowSource = vbNullString
Me.ListBox1.Clear
Me.ListBox1.ColumnCount = 27
Me.ListBox1.ColumnWidths = "30 pt;65 pt;65 pt;65 pt;65 pt;130 pt;130 pt;49.95 pt;30 pt;45 pt;35 pt;65 pt;65 pt;65 pt;80 pt;65 pt;49.95 pt;30 pt;30 pt;30 pt;30 pt;100 pt;59 pt;65 pt;65 pt;30 pt;65 pt"


a = Range("C2:C" & Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Resize(, 27).Value2
ReDim o(1 To 27, 1 To UBound(a, 1))

For i = 1 To UBound(a, 1)
If UCase(a(i, 11)) Like UCase(Me.TextBox1.Value) & "*" Then
    n = n + 1
    For c = 1 To UBound(a, 2)
        o(c, n) = a(i, c)
    Next
End If
Next

 If n Then
    ReDim Preserve o(1 To 27, 1 To n)
    Me.ListBox1.List = Application.Transpose(o)
 End If

End Sub
```

Comment: shrinks horizontally??

Comment: yes, it shrink horizontally

Comment: my bad, it shrink vertically